# Using user input as variables in Python

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to implement a "user-friendly" portfolio optimization program in Python.
Since I am still a beginner I did not quite manage to realize it.

The only thing the program should use as input are the stock codes.

I tried to create a mwe below:

```
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

def daily_returns(price):
    price = price.to_numpy()
    shift_1 = price[1:]
    shift_2 = price[:-1]
    return (shift_1 - shift_2)/shift_1

def annual_returns(price):
    price = price.to_numpy()
    start = price[0]
    end = price[len(price)-1]
    return (end-start)/start

def adjusting(price):
    adj = len(price)
    diff = adj - adjvalue
    if diff != 0:
        price_new = price[:-diff]
    else: price_new = price
    return price_new

#Minimal Reproducible Example

#getting user input
names = input('Stock codes:')
names = names.split()
a = len(names)
msft = yf.Ticker(names[0])
aapl = yf.Ticker(names[1])

#import data
hist_msft = msft.history(interval='1d',start='2020-01-01',end='2020-12-31')
hist_msft = pd.DataFrame(hist_msft,columns=['Close'])
#hist_msft = hist_msft.to_numpy()

hist_aapl = aapl.history(interval='1d',start='2020-01-01',end='2020-12-31')
hist_aapl = pd.DataFrame(hist_aapl,columns=['Close'])
#hist_aapl = hist_aapl.to_numpy()

#daily returns
aapl_daily_returns = daily_returns(hist_aapl)
aapl_daily_returns = np.ravel(aapl_daily_returns)

msft_daily_returns = daily_returns(hist_msft)
msft_daily_returns = np.ravel(msft_daily_returns)

#adjusting for different trading periods
adjvalue = min(len(aapl_daily_returns),len(msft_daily_returns))
aapl_adj = adjusting(aapl_daily_returns)
msft_adj = adjusting(msft_daily_returns)

#annual returns
aapl_ann_returns = annual_returns(hist_aapl)
msft_ann_returns = annual_returns(hist_msft)

#inputs for optimization
cov_mat = np.cov([aapl_adj,msft_adj])*252
ann_returns = np.concatenate((aapl_ann_returns,msft_ann_returns))
```

Now I just want the code to work with a various, unknown number of inputs. I tried reading a lot about global variables or tried to figure it out with dictionaries but couldn't really achieve any progress.

Comment: So you mean instead of MSFT or AAPL process whichever symbols the user gave as input? The code already does that, it's just that the variable names are misleading.

Comment: Are you always trying to compare two stocks? If so, you have already done the job.  Just rename msft to stock1 and aapl to stock2 wherever they appear in the code.

Comment: Oh I think then I wasn't precise enough. I want this code to work for an undefined number of stocks. So in case the user wants to know the efficient portfolio frontier for, lets say, 10 stocks, he just has to input MSFT, AAPL, AMZN, INTC etc. I think a for loop (like in the answer below) could be the right approach for that...

Answer (score -1):

I think using the `for` loop can solve your problem!

```py
...
names = input('Stock codes:')
names = names.split()
for name in names:
    #analyze here
    #I don't know anything about stocks so I wont write anything here
...
```